# Spivak Calculus, Ch. 4 Graphs, Problem 19v: How to interpret graph in solution manual?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Describe as best you can the graphs of the following functions (a
> complete picture is usually out of the question):
>
> v) $f(x)$ = the number obtained by replacing all digits in the decimal
> expansion of $x$ which come after the first $7$ (if any) by $0$.

**I will show my solution below, and then the solution manual solution. My question is essentially how to interpret the graph given by the solution manual. I want to determine if my solution presented below agrees at all with the solution manual.**

**My solution**

Here are some examples of $f(x)$:

$$f(0.77)=0.7$$
$$f(0.07)=0.07$$
$$f(7.\bar{72})=7.70\bar{72}$$
$$f(3)=3$$
$$f(-0.77)=-0.7$$

For positive $x$, $f$ basically subtracts at most $0.07$ from $x$. For negative $x$, $f$ adds at most $0.07$ to $x$. Numbers with no sevens in them stay the same.

In any interval of real numbers, intuitively (at this point in Spivak I don't have the machinery available to prove this) there are an infinite number of numbers with sevens in them, and an infinite number of numbers without sevens in them.

I imagine that for $x>0$ $f$ tracks the function defined as $x$, but with an infinite number of points in between the line $x$ and the line $x-0.07$.

For $x<0$, $f$ has an infinite number of points between the line $x$ and the line $x+0.07$.

**Here is what I drew up:**

[image]

**The solution manual shows a what appears to be a different solution:**

[image]

**My question is: how do I interpret this graph from the solution manual? Is my answer and graph at all related to this graph from the solution manual?**

Comment: Your understanding of $f(x)$ is wrong. See the third example. $f(7.727...)=7$. *All* digits after the first $7$ are zero, nut just the first one

Answer (score 1):

In my original answer I read the problem description incorrectly. We must replace **all digits** in the decimal expansion of $x$ which come after the first $7$.

For example, between $x=0.7$ and $x=0.8=0.7\bar{9}$, $f(x)=0.7$. This is the large interval we see in the solution manual solution.

Note that for $x=0.7=0.6\bar{9}$, $f(0.7)$ does not equal 0.7 apparently because $0.6\bar{9}$ is used.

Another example is the interval between $x=0.697$ and $x=0.698$. $f(x)=0.697$ in this interval except at $x=0.697=0.696\bar{9}$.

In the interval between $x=0.6967$ and $x=0.6968$ we have $f(x)=0.6967$ except at $x=0.6967=0.696\bar{9}$

Function $f$ seems to be composed of infinite intervals like this, mixed with points on the line $y=x$ for numbers with no sevens in them.

Consider $x=1.7$. Again we have a larger interval between $x=1.7$ and $x=1.8$ in which $f(x)=1.7$ except at $x=1.7$.